# how to i invoke an alert() in angular 2.

Tags: angular, typescript

My question really is that basic.  Im a.net developer working on a proof of concept. Angular2 is completely new to me.  As a c# developer I am pleased by typescript and its ability to behave in a strongly typed fashion but am disappointed in how even the most basic of things such as integrating jquery and invoking a popup seen to not work.  I can do all this from the main.js file which is referenced in my index page but not so much from the component.  What gives? Im currently looking for a good basic starter kit if anyone knows of a particularly good one. 
Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htBob.png)

Comment: window.alert('hello'); just as everywhere else. TypeScript and Angular are complex beasts that need to be learnt. If you expect being able to improvize because you already know jQuery, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should write like

alert('test');

And this will show  at the top of page an alert with name Test

Comment: Yes it should. I believe i have something configured so far off that its not even getting hit.